# Long-lasting durability

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, redundancy

If a sentence contains 'long-lasting durability,' is it redundant?

For example: Robust plastic construction ensures long-lasting durability.

Long-lasting and durability, do they mean the same thing?

Thank you

Comment: [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/durability) - *Use the noun durability to describe the quality of permanence or strength that keeps something working or holds it together. Your parents' thirty year marriage has durability, and your sturdy old car that keeps on running mile after mile also has durability. The Latin root word, durabilis, means "lasting or permanent," and comes from durare, "to last or harden."*

Comment: ... FF's 'your sturdy old car that keeps on running mile after mile also has durability' shows that 'durability' is [sometimes] used in a non-absolute way (the car will not be running in another 200 years). So it is reasonable to qualify 'durability'. But I'd find a different intensifier. '... ensures that they are highly durable.'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: So we should reserve "durable" for things that *really* last a long time? Such as [***xenon-124***](https://news.uchicago.edu/story/scientists-measure-half-life-element-thats-longer-age-universe), which apparently has a half-life one trillion times longer than the age of the universe.

Answer (score 1):

It can be redundant, but not always.

When being used in scientific writing to describe a physical property, you substantiate it with some sort of measurement or quality descriptor. 
 "Durability" is the attribute being measured.  "Long-lasting" is the measure of how durable it is.

If a plastic construction only held together for a matter of seconds before falling apart, I could still say it is durable.  I just left off the important measure of it being "not very" durable and having "short-lasting" durability relative to what one would expect.

When used in everyday writing, "durability" does imply long-lasting or strong.

Answer (score -1):

*Robust plastic construction ensures  long-lasting  durability*

Long-longisting durability  is  an example  of  redundancy.

I think  it  is  Indian English  and  is  an example  of  tautology.

So  the  correct  sentence  may  be:

> Robust plastic construction ensures durability.

*Durability* means the ability  to  withstand wear, pressure, or damage.

or

> The  fact  of something  continuing  to  be  used without getting  damaged.

Here is the  link.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/durability

Comment: You have cited here a meaning for "durable" and not durability. Durability as how I imagine it to be (and similar to how you'd say of any word with suffix "ability" -- combustibility, disability, inflexibility, etc.) is a degree to which something is durable.

Comment: @ Jitesh.When the  meaning  of  durable  is  clear, we  can  understand  the  meaning  of  the  noun durability.The  Dictionary  entries  show  only  the  meanings  of  adjectives.Anyhow, it  is  Indian English  and  redundant

Comment: Inadequate data or logic to back your claim, @Englishmonger. The meaning of adjective doesn't automatically infer the meaning of its noun.

Comment: The usage for suffix "-ability" can be stated as, "used with adjectives ending in ‘-able’ to make nouns meaning a particular quality." The emphasis is on "particular quality"; it therefore denotes a sense of degree the noun can take of its related adjective.

Source: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ability_2

(Indian English, really? How about this: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20648442)

Comment: "Despite successes, the candidacy of the 37-year-old mayor of the city of 100,000 continues to face skepticism about its long-term durability, particularly over his ability to attract support from African Americans."

Source: https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/at-iowas-democratic-dinner-warren-and-buttigieg-take-aim-at-one-another/2019/11/02/6175bd34-fd8a-11e9-8906-ab6b60de9124_story.html

Comment: Some examples of tautology are accepted and even preferred in English. I myself use them in some contexts.

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth.Is it  correct  and  acceptable  in the  context and in the  sentence?